# ATtiny85 LM75 I2C

Tags: i2c, attiny

I would like to read temperature from a [LM75](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/LM75.pdf) using the **ATtiny85** running [a core by SpenceKonde](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) and utilizing the [TinyWireM](https://github.com/adafruit/TinyWireM) library.

My Logic Analyzer does not pick up any I2C communication, when I connect it to an Arduino Nano, it works fine. On the Nano, there is no need for **TinyWireM** so that's a big difference.

Therefore I conclude that the ATtiny85 is not speaking the right I2C slang to the device.

I also use SoftwareSerial and this works fine. It is visible on the Logic Analyzer.

[image]

The [LM75 library](https://github.com/thefekete/LM75) is not made for ATtiny or TinyWireM, I replace the `Wire` references in-place by `TinyWireM` reference.

Should it be possible to 'just' replace Wire by TineWireM in the library and could I expect some meaningful data this way?

**[updated code]**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TinyWireM.h>
#include <LM75.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SOFTWARE_SERIAL_TX_PIN 3
#define SOFTWARE_SERIAL_RX_PIN -1

LM75 sensor;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(SOFTWARE_SERIAL_RX_PIN, SOFTWARE_SERIAL_TX_PIN);

void setup() {
  TinyWireM.begin();
  mySerial.begin(2400);
  mySerial.print("Starting..");
}

void loop() {
delay(1000);
mySerial.println("SO");
mySerial.println(sensor.temp());
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I have added te code I use to test

Comment: Looks like the setup() is missing a call to TinyWireM.begin(). Also do not forget pullup resistors.

Comment: The `TinyWireM.begin()` is part of the library and I have the pull-ups, this setup works on an Arduino Nano

Comment: i2c is fairly easy to implement, either hardware or software. so you may find it beneficial to just write your own.

Comment: @Thijs The setup cannot work on Nano as it does not support USI which is the ATtiny hardware module.

Comment: Use LM35 which is analog.

Answer (score 2):

The current ATtiny core includes a Wire library for the USI hardware used in the Tinys. This way you don't need to modify the LM75 library which is error prone.

Comment: Thanks, that piece of the code went missing when I edited the question (6 months ago). Problem remains.

Comment: Might help if you update the code to what you're actually using. Keep in mind that you won't see anything in the resolution you've chosen in the logic analyzer as I2C is about 50 times faster than the serial.

Comment: I updated the six months old question you answered with the code I might have used back then. But please tell me more about the speed of I2C.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Arduino SE community. Please expand on your answer. You have identified some issues but please update your answer with how to resolve these issues. For example you could demonstrate the solution with some snippets of code and an explaination of how it fixes the problems the OP is having.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post I know but hopefully this information is helpful to someone. I modified the lm75 library by replacing all instances of Wire with TinyWire and as above no go, but turns out a 10k pull up on SCL / SDA is a necessity for the attiny 85. For whatever reason i2c works fine on an arduino UNO without pull ups but not on an attiny 85. So in short, add pull up resistors and it works. Bonus potato grade picture of attiny, LM75 and display module showing temperature.

[image]

Comment: hi Tom, thanks for the reply and the great picture :D could you please share information about your code? what library and core you used for example. I’ll try it out but I think I had the pullups back then..

Comment: I pretty much just used the lm75 and TinyWireM library, made a copy of the lm75 library, renamed it to lm75tiny and replaced any instances of Wire with TinyWireM. Ended up with this:  

#include <TinyWireM.h>  

#include <lm75tiny.h>

TempI2C_LM75 termo = TempI2C_LM75(0x49,TempI2C_LM75::nine_bits);  

Then read temperature like so:  

int temp = termo.getTemp();

Only other gotcha is the address of the lm75 needs to be confirmed and updated for whatever sensor you are using. I think the default is 0x48 but my sensor was 0x49.